# el rgpd donde habla de sitios web?

Tags: javascript, php, css, local-storage, cookies

por seguridad apenas carga mi sitio web puse una cookie con setcookie() con nombre, duración y le dí el ID del usuario tambien estoy pensando usar localStorage(el problema es que el usuario podría modificar el localStorage), fui a buscar en el [reglamento general de protección de datos](https://commission.europa.eu/law/law-topic/data-protection/data-protection-eu_es) que cosas tengo que avisarle al usuario o la visita sobre la cookie que le puse en su navegador y sobre el uso del localStorage y cuando cargue por primera vez el sitio web del [reglamento general de protección de datos](https://commission.europa.eu/law/law-topic/data-protection/data-protection-eu_es) metió 3 cookies en mi navegador sin haber aceptado las cookies de entrada, puedo meterle una cookie al usuario sin que haya aceptado las cookies?

[image: reglamentoGeneralDeProteccionDeDatos]

Comment: En la primera frase lo dice todo "...tratamiento de los **datos personales**"

Comment: De acuerdo con el Reglamento General de Protección de Datos (RGPD), es necesario obtener el consentimiento del usuario antes de almacenar cookies en su dispositivo, excepto en el caso de cookies estrictamente necesarias para el funcionamiento del sitio web. Las cookies estrictamente necesarias son aquellas que son esenciales para proporcionar los servicios solicitados por el usuario. Si la cookie que estás utilizando es esencial para el funcionamiento de tu sitio web, puedes almacenarla sin obtener el consentimiento previo del usuario. Sin embargo, si la cookie no es estrictamente necesaria, d

Comment: Inkinvissible solo quiero poner ID de seguridad para evitar el spam de los usuarios, darles roles dentro de la pagina y se puedan comunicar entre ellos de forma anónima por que la página tiene un chat, crees que eso sea un motivo estrictamente necesario para el funcionamiento de la pagina?

Comment: Totalmente, porque constituye un servicio que estás ofreciendo. A mi parecer, sí, sí es estrictamente necesario.  Saludos!

Comment: Inkinvissible Gracias

Comment: Un placer haberte podido ayudar!!!